# Get View for SettingsActivity/SettingsFragment from PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, preferencefragmentcompat

I've got a SettingsFragment with a SwitchPreferenceCompat-Control

```
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="my_key"
        app:title="@string/prefs_my_title" />
```

Background: I'm using https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide and want to lead the user through the necessary settings - **So how can I get a handle (must be a view) on my switch to pass it to Tourguide?**

I already tried to get a handle by

```
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:id="@+id/myId"
        app:key="my_key"
        app:title="@string/prefs_my_title" />

    getView().findViewById(R.id.myId)
```

But since getView() returning null I cannot get any further with this approach.

How can I get/pass the particulary views from SwitchPreferenceCompat or EditTextPreference from inside the SettingsActivity/-Fragment?

Any help would be welcome - if someone knows a better tool than tourguide - especially for showing preferences - please also let me know.

**Update:**

```
  public void onResume() {          

        View view = getView();
        
        // This should be my SwitchPreferenceCompat
        View targetView = view.findViewById(R.id.myId);
        
        Log.d("view", ""+view);
        Log.d("viewId", ""+view.getId());
        Log.d("targetView", ""+targetView);

        super.onResume();
   }
```

Brings up the following:

```
    D/view: android.widget.LinearLayout{1afdad5 V.E..V... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
    D/viewId: -1
    D/targetView: null
```

So I now got a view, but it doesn't seem to be the one I defined, the ID of the linear Layout ist not the one from the settings_activity.xml (I cannot get any other view from the xml by ID)

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
        android:id="@+id/linearId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"></Button>
        
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        
        
        </LinearLayout>
```

and the SwitchPreference is also not found by ID. Any ideas so far? Since this threads gets longer -> if someone got a simple example how to fetch the view of a dynamically generated SwitchPreferenceCompat-Control -> you're welcome, also are you Zain and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: From where did you call `getView()`?

Comment: I could call it here

`public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: or here

`public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat{
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) { `

Comment: I'd call it anywhere, if it only would work.

Comment: try it in `onResume()` within the `SettingsFragment`

Comment: Thank you. Ok, one step ahead: now it gives me view in linear layout. First thougt it was the one I definied so I checked the id, see above Update.